# Identify this card game with a 52-Card deck and two teams

Tags: identify-this-game

I played this card game without knowing its name and had forgotten some rules. So here is a description of the game.

It is for 3-12 players and players team up as the good or the bad. (Played using a 52- card deck) Players will sit in a circle.
A dealer will not take part in the game and will choose who to be good people and who to be bad people. This is done by giving a  red card (bad team) or a black card (good team) to the players by lying face down. (The identity of every player is unknown to the others at the start) The bad players must be lesser than the good players. (Ex: 3 Good Players and 2 Bad Players or 4 Good Players and 2 Bad Players)
A few special identities are given to some players like 
-(The Queen of Spades - Leader of Good Team)
-(The Queen of Hearts - Leader of Bad Team)
-(The King of Spades and The King of Hearts which I had forgotten their role)

Once done, the players will "sleep" by putting their heads down. 
a) The dealer will call up the bad players so they will know who their allies are. Then, they will be asked to sleep again.
b) Now, the Kings and Queens are asked to rise (Which I forgot too, so it might be untrue)
c) Then, everyone will be asked to sleep again. Once done, everybody rise and the game begins.
d) The dealer chooses a player to begin the game and he or she must choose two players to play with her.
e) Each chosen player (3 in total) will be given a black card (spades or clubs) and a red card (hearts or diamonds)
f) Then, they will choose a card to place at the centre (The good can only place black cards while the bad can place either one)
g) The motive here in part 1 is to win 5 points by either the good or bad. (The good wins if all the card placed in the centre are black while the bad wins if one of the cards at the centre is red)
h) Therefore, the good players have to identify their allies while the bad players have to trick the good players into choosing them to place their cards
i) The game continues with the left person of the last chooser and he or she now choose 3 players instead of two.
j) The increase in a chosen player will go on until a team reaches 5 points or the max number of good players are reached. (Ex: If there are 6 good players, the increase will stop until only 6 players are chosen per game) 
k) The part one of the game ends when a team reaches 5 points.

Part 2- The part that I forgot (might be untrue)
a) Players are required to guess the leaders of each team and will try to prevent the other team from knowing their team leaders
b) The team who identifies the other team's queen wins.

Comment: Sounds a lot like [The Resistance](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/41114/resistance), just with some house rules.

Comment: Indeed, I would say that this is a some sort of The Resistance. If you're going to proxy the game with a standard deck of cards, you'll want to study the official rules in more depth. Also, you can see the number of players per mission (at each player count) here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Resistance_(game)

Answer (score 3):

[The Resistance with Regular Playing Cards](http://www.brianathomas.com/archives/2013/12/15/resistance-with-regular-playing-cards/)

and see

[The Resistance (with Standard Playing Cards)](https://lodumsgamecorner.blogspot.com/2015/07/the-resistance-with-standard-playing.html)